# pandas not defined even after importing it

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
worksheet_1 = pd.read_excel(r"X:\data for feature analysis\Chitra\Chitra_walking\t1.xlsx")

pandas.__version__


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16988/2084971433.py in <module>
----> 1 pandas.__version__

NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined
```

Comment: Either just `import pandas` or use the name you have defined `pd.__version__`.

Comment: That is not the proper duplicate for this question. This is a confusion about variable naming during import.

Answer (score 3):

You are importing as "pd" so refer to it that way, not as "pandas".  e.g.

```py
pd.__version__
# or for extensive information
pd.show_versions()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `import` keyword imports modules and packages and then assigns them to variables in your namespace. `import pandas` imports the package and assigns it to the variable `pandas`. `import pandas as pd` imports the same package but assigns it to the variable `pd`. Reference the package as

```
pd.__version__
```

There is nothing special about these variables. The importer assigns the module to the variable, but you can always (usually in error) assign a different value in the future.